# specifying a kernel header dependency in dpkg for module build

Tags: kernel-module, dpkg

I have a dpkg that is dependent upon the having the kernel headers to compile a dkms based kernel module.  I know I can get the proper headers installed by executing
`apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but that I can not do this within the preinst or postinst scripts.  Nor can I list `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` as a dependency in the control Depends entry.

Is there any way of declaring a dpkg dependency that is dependent of the kernel version?

I am using `fakeroot dh binary` to do the packaging.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.  I am compiling on a raspberrypi and by adding `raspberrypi-kernel-headers` to the Depends: line of the debian/control file it picks up the proper headers.